# Getting statistics of a table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, statistics

What is more efficient to gather table statistics:

1. Using `dbms_stats.gather_table_stats`?
2. Using `analyze table`?

Comment: as both the functions serve the purpose of giving the row length of a table, just wanna know which one is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not recommended to use `analyze` to gather statistics (from 8i onward) because CBO(cost base optimizer) is build to recognize statistics that have been gathered using `dbms_stats`. So `dbms_stats` is a preferable way to gather statistics.